# python postgres force varchar

Tags: python, postgresql, batch-insert

I have a tuple like so `('35367911000001103', '0001')` and im trying to use mogrify to insert both these values as a string but it keeps complaining that its out of range as an integer. The field is not an integer, its VARCHAR(255).

```
psycopg2.DataError: value "35367911000001103" is out of range for type integer
```

How can I force this value to be a string/varchar like its set out to be?

```
args_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s, %s)", x).decode('utf-8') for x in vpi_tuples)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES %s" % (table_name, args_str))
```

Comment: Why not use a `big int`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: What if I don't want it numeric and store it as a string? Is that the only way, any idea why %s would just convert this string to a numeric value? i.e what if the value was '35367911000001103A' further down the tuple array?

Comment: Do you really need `mogrify`? What about something like http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-exec ?

Comment: I replaced mogrify with your suggestion and that worked. If you can put this as an answer I can mark it off.